# Tensorflow: Passing CSV with 3D feature array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, tensorflow

My current text file that I intend to use for LSTM training in Tensorflow looks like this:

```
> 0.2, 4.3, 1.2
> 1.1, 2.2, 3.1
> 3.5, 4.1, 1.1, 4300
> 
> 1.2, 3.3, 1.2
> 1.5, 2.4, 3.1
> 3.5, 2.1, 1.1, 4400
> 
> ...
```

There are 3 sequences 3 features vectors with only 1 label for each sample. I formatted this text file so it can be consistent with the LSTM training as the latter requires a time-steps of the sequences or in general, LSTM training requires a 3D tensor (batch, num of time-steps, num of features).

My question: How should I use Numpy or `TensorFlow.TextReader` in order to reformat the 3x3 sequence vectors and the singleton Labels so it can become compatible with Tensorflow?

Edit: I saw many tutorials on reformatting text or CSV files that has vectors and labels but unfortunately they were for 1 to 1 relationships e.g.

```
0.2, 4.3, 1.2, Class1
1.1, 2.2, 3.1, Class2
3.5, 4.1, 1.1, Class3
```

becomes:

```
[0.2, 4.3, 1.2, Class1], [1.1, 2.2, 3.1, Class2], [3.5, 4.1, 1.1, Class3]
```

which clearly is readable by Numpy and can build vectors easily from it dedicated for simple Feed-Forward NN tasks. But this procedure doesn't actually build an LSTM friendly CSV.

EDIT: The TensorFlow tutorial on CSV formats, covers only 2D arrays as an example. The `features = col1, col2, col3` doesn't assume that there might be time-steps for each sequence array and hence my question.

Comment: any reason you can't use pandas for this? If not you probably could do something with numpy's `reshape`, `ravel`, and `view` - or a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to whether you are more interested in the `numpy` array(s) structure, or the csv fomat.

The `np.savetxt` csv file writer can't readily produce text like:

```
0.2, 4.3, 1.2
1.1, 2.2, 3.1
3.5, 4.1, 1.1, 4300

1.2, 3.3, 1.2
1.5, 2.4, 3.1
3.5, 2.1, 1.1, 4400
```

`savetxt` is not tricky.  It opens a file for writing, and then iterates on the input array, writing it, one row at a time to the file.  Effectively:

```
 for row in arr:
    f.write(fmt % tuple(row))
```

where `fmt` has a `%` field for each element of the the `row`.  In the simple case it constructs `fmt = delimiter.join(['fmt']*(arr.shape[1]))`.  In other words repeating the simgle field `fmt` for the number of columns.  Or you can give it a multifield `fmt`.

So you could use normal line/file writing methods to write a custom display.  The simplest is to construct it using the usual `print` commends, and then redirect those to a file.

But having done that, there's the question of how to read that back into a `numpy` session.  `np.genfromtxt` can handle missing data, but you still have to include the delimiters.   It's also trickier to have it read blocks (3 lines separated by a blank line).  It's not impossible, but you have to do some preprocessing.

Of course `genfromtxt` isn't that tricky either.  It reads the file line by line, converts each line into a list of numbers or strings, and collects those lists in a master list.  Only at the end is that list converted into an array.

I can construct an array like your text with:

```
In [121]: dt = np.dtype([('lbl',int), ('block', float, (3,3))])
In [122]: A = np.zeros((2,),dtype=dt)
In [123]: A
Out[123]: 
array([(0, [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]),
       (0, [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])], 
      dtype=[('lbl', '<i4'), ('block', '<f8', (3, 3))])
In [124]: A['lbl']=[4300,4400]
In [125]: A[0]['block']=np.array([[.2,4.3,1.2],[1.1,2.2,3.1],[3.5,4.1,1.1]])
In [126]: A
Out[126]: 
array([(4300, [[0.2, 4.3, 1.2], [1.1, 2.2, 3.1], [3.5, 4.1, 1.1]]),
       (4400, [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])], 
      dtype=[('lbl', '<i4'), ('block', '<f8', (3, 3))])
In [127]: A['block']
Out[127]: 
array([[[ 0.2,  4.3,  1.2],
        [ 1.1,  2.2,  3.1],
        [ 3.5,  4.1,  1.1]],

       [[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ]]])
```

I can load it from a txt that has all the block values flattened:

```
In [130]: txt=b"""4300, 0.2, 4.3, 1.2, 1.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.5, 4.1, 1.1"""
In [131]: txt
Out[131]: b'4300, 0.2, 4.3, 1.2, 1.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.5, 4.1, 1.1'
```

`genfromtxt` can handle a complex dtype, allocating values in order from the flat line list:

```
In [133]: data=np.genfromtxt([txt],delimiter=',',dtype=dt)
In [134]: data['lbl']
Out[134]: array(4300)
In [135]: data['block']
Out[135]: 
array([[ 0.2,  4.3,  1.2],
       [ 1.1,  2.2,  3.1],
       [ 3.5,  4.1,  1.1]])
```

I'm not sure about writing it.  I have have to reshape it into a 10 column  or field array, if I want to use `savetxt`.

Comment: Do you suggest I reformat my CSV into a one-line shaped 2D arrays i.e. [[0.2, 4.3, 1.2], [...], [...], 4300] and then pass it easily using Tf.TextReader? If I do that, Tensorflow can easily know there are x number of features in each sample (1st value of each 1D vector), and y number of time-steps (# 1D vectors) and then I can initialize a placeholder for the last element in the 2D vector.

Comment: I don't know about the `TextReader`.  The `numpy` readers can't handle brackets, but `tf` might.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** addition to the previos answer:

```
df.stack().to_csv('d:/temp/1D.csv', index=False)
```

1D.csv:

```
0.2
4.3
1.2
4300.0
1.1
2.2
3.1
4300.0
3.5
4.1
1.1
4300.0
1.2
3.3
1.2
4400.0
1.5
2.4
3.1
4400.0
3.5
2.1
1.1
4400.0
```

**OLD answer:**

Here is a Pandas solution.

Assume we have the following text file:

```
0.2, 4.3, 1.2
1.1, 2.2, 3.1
3.5, 4.1, 1.1, 4300

1.2, 3.3, 1.2
1.5, 2.4, 3.1
3.5, 2.1, 1.1, 4400
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

In [95]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\data.txt'

In [96]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=',', skipinitialspace=True, header=None, names=list('abcd'))

In [97]: df
Out[97]:
     a    b    c       d
0  0.2  4.3  1.2     NaN
1  1.1  2.2  3.1     NaN
2  3.5  4.1  1.1  4300.0
3  1.2  3.3  1.2     NaN
4  1.5  2.4  3.1     NaN
5  3.5  2.1  1.1  4400.0

In [98]: df.d = df.d.bfill()

In [99]: df
Out[99]:
     a    b    c       d
0  0.2  4.3  1.2  4300.0
1  1.1  2.2  3.1  4300.0
2  3.5  4.1  1.1  4300.0
3  1.2  3.3  1.2  4400.0
4  1.5  2.4  3.1  4400.0
5  3.5  2.1  1.1  4400.0
```

now you can save it back to CSV:

```
df.to_csv('d:/temp/out.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

d:/temp/out.csv:

```
0.2,4.3,1.2,4300.0
1.1,2.2,3.1,4300.0
3.5,4.1,1.1,4300.0
1.2,3.3,1.2,4400.0
1.5,2.4,3.1,4400.0
3.5,2.1,1.1,4400.0
```

Comment: Thanks Max. But such final result won't cause a problem of duplicates whenever i want to define the last column as a label array?

Comment: @Leb_Broth, i'm not sure i understand you... Can you make an example?

Comment: It's ok i get it now. I can use 2 nested for loops, 1 for building the (3x3) 2D array and before the loop starts again i push into a new array the value of the corresponding label (4300) col4. Then later i can pass them easily to TensorFlow.

Comment: @Leb_Broth, no, you don't want to use nested loops when using Pandas/NumPy - it ruins the whole idea of using vectorized approaches. Can you explain what do you need for `TensorFlow`? Do you need a list/dict of (3x3) 2D arrays?

Comment: The following tutorial https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py is very similar to my case. Here TensorFlow needs to recognize that there are 28 features (columns) and 28 sequences (rows) and a class for each 28x28 image. But this example doesn't include a CSV data load. And there are no tutorials yet to show a working example for passing a CSV file like mine to the placeholders of TensorFlow.

Comment: @Leb_Broth, you may want to try [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) - look for "CSV files" on that page

Comment: based on that, which is for 1D vectors, I should include a new Sequence=row1, row2, row3 and also alter the For loop and iterate i every 3 lines. Ill try and pot the results.

Comment: @Leb_Broth, could you update your question with the desired output that you need for the TensorFlow - i'm pretty sure there is vectorized solution, which doesn't require to use loops

Comment: i just did. Thanks a lot.